# Which is perfect Data Structure for exact string pattern matching?

Tags: data-structures, pattern-matching

I am working on web content filtering where there is 10000 of words coming on a page. I have to match this with my 1500-2500words dictionary. And I have to find out whether any words present in the page or not.

Please suggest me best data structure to store my pattern faster searching.
I have studied Tree structure. But lets take a word (abc) that may have 26possibilities for a next character. I have to keep 26pointers for next node. (It consumes 26x4 Bytes). I cant spend that much memory for storing my patterns each word.

Suggest me best searching and best in memory.

I am beginner in this field.

Comment: With a trie, you don't have to "keep 26 pointers for next node". You can dynamically allocate the an array of sorted pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is solved exactly by [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).  After some pre-processing you can process each webpage in O(n) time, where n is the size of that page.  You will need an amount of auxiliary storage roughly as large as your dictionary.

Your memory constraints seem pretty severe, but if you really need to reduce your memory footprint you can use a list of all characters present at a given state rather than having an array of 26 characters at each state.  You will need to scan through these characters as you process a web page, which will slow you down by a fairly significant constant factor, but you will save on space.

Comment: I have implemented aho-corasick for 2000 pattens, Each pattern consists of 121-123charachters. I have created next link and suffix link (failure link) for faster searching. But it consumes 4.5Mb for 293046 characters. Can we reduce this tree to 1MB.

Comment: My structure is:
struct _treenode {
    char ch;
    short int child; //(for next children's count)
    char *value; //(for stroring pattern name)
    struct _treenode **next; //(next child link)
    struct _treenode *suffixlink; //(failure link)
};

Comment: If you really want to save space I would suggest the following:
1. child: This value can only go as high as your alphabet, so it should only be a byte.
2. value: don't store the name as a pointer, I'm assuming you have these names lying around somewhere, so just store an index into that array.  This pointer (assuming you're on a 32-bit system) is taking up four bytes, but if you only have 2k words then you only need two bytes to index into an array of that size.
If you can do 1 and 2 then you'll save 25% on space because your struct will drop from 16 bytes to 12.  That's a start at least.

Comment: I would also suggest making next and suffixlink indices into an array, as long as you have fewer than 2^16 states (you might not, though).

Answer (score 0):

For best search is trie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
And for best memory and a god complexity for a search i suggest you a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array or a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree
Another approach is by sorting your dictionary(O(NlogN)), and your words O(MlogM) and than with one traversal you check if there is a match for each element O(N + M).
You start with 2 index , and at each step you increase one of them based on the result of comparing the string of the dictionary at one index with the word you have at second index , if they match you have a match and go to the next word you have, else if your word is lower than the dictionary word you go to the next word ( because you allready went through all the dictionary word before that and did not find a match ) else you go to the next element in to the dictionary( try to find a word in to the dictionary that is not lower than your word)